# How would I wiggle only on the y-axis when using wiggle with the slider expression control?

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

How would I use the wiggle expression only on the y-axis?

I'm using two sliders. The first for the frequency and the second for the amplitude.

Here's my expression so far. This works but wiggles on both the x and y axis. I just want the y only. How would I ammend the expression below?

```
wiggle(effect("Slider Control")("Slider"),effect("Slider Control 2")("Slider"))
```

update:

the following seems to work:

```
[position[0],wiggle(effect("Slider Control")("Slider"),effect("Slider Control 2")("Slider"))[1]]
```

any advice is still appreciated

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
amp = effect("amplitude")("Slider");
freq = effect("frequency")("Slider");
wiggle(freq, amp, octaves = 1, amp_mult = .5, t = time)
```

1. Add sliders to the layer you want to wiggle. Call them "amp" and "freq".
2. Right click on the position control on the layer you want to wiggle.
3. Select "separate dimensions".  The x and y controls will now be seperate.
4. Apply the expression above to whichever dimension you want to control.

[image: grab]